# Largest cycle can't have too many neighbours

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices with $\delta(G)\geq1000\sqrt n$, and suppose $C$ is a cycle of maximum length in $G$. It's not hard to see that $C$ consists of at least $\delta(G)+1$ vertices.

Now let $S$ be the set of vertices in $G$ each of which has $\geq 100\sqrt n$ neighbours on the cycle $C$. I want to show that $|S|\leq 100\sqrt n$.

[image]

I am trying to use an argument which would contradict the maximality of the cycle if $S$ has more than $100\sqrt n$ elements, but I am not managing to get a contradiction. I would appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: What is $d$ here? The statement is not true for all $d$.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Let's say $d=K\sqrt n$ where $K$ is some large constant, and $n=|V(G)|$.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false as written.

Consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n/3, 2n/3}$ for some very large $n$; here, the minimum degree is $\frac n3$, much bigger than $1000 \sqrt n$. A cycle $C$ of maximum length exhausts the side with $\frac n3$ vertices, and uses $\frac n3$ more vertices on the side with $\frac{2n}{3}$ vertices.

Then $S$, the set of vertices with more than $100\sqrt n$ neighbors on $C$, consists of all $\frac n3$ remaining vertices. Each one of them has $\frac n3$ neighbors on $C$, in fact. So $|S|$ is much bigger than $100\sqrt n$.